# Using groff to generate pdf man pages for a c program file

Tags: c, manpage, groff

Give a working c code how to use `groff` to generate man pages for it in pdf format 
.
Is it something that can be automatically generated or does it require any manual 
file creation? The only instruction I have is to use `groff with the “man” macro package`

Comment: Groff has pdf support. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/groff.1.html What is the question?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want exactly. Working C code is generally written in C, while manuals are generally written in English. Do you expect that there exist an automatic way to convert one to the other?

Comment: Yes i was looking for way to convert a working C code to man page. what does groff do then?
Like if i want to build a man page for my c program what will be steps to do it and how will groff come into picture

Answer (score 0):

Groff (with the macros for man pages) format the text in the appropriate way. You still need to write the text. The `man` macros ore or less force you to write the pages in the correct format.

There is no way that you can generate man pages from a C program automatically. The program tells the computer what to do, the man pages tell the user what to do. These are completely different concepts.